# fopen() opens the text file successfully for sometime and fails after a specific time

Tags: c, windows, winapi, text-files, fopen

I am trying to send a text file at a socket after every 10ms. The code works fine and keeps on sending the text file over the socket after an interval of 10ms. But after some period of time (like after 3-4 minutes), fopen() fils (though fopen() works fine for some duration) and I get an error "Unhandled exception at 0x011f28f7 in Client2.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow." and a break at

> ```
>    test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.
> ```

in "chkstk.asm".

what could be the possible reason for this? How fopen() works fine for sometime and fails afterwards?

Please help me :(

**CODE:**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   char timer[1000];
    switch(msg)
      {      case WM_TIMER: 
            switch(wParam) 
               { 
                  case IDT_TIMER1: 
                   {        
                    FILE *fpSend ;
                    if((fpSend = fopen("Client4.txt", "r+b")) == NULL)
                    {
                  MessageBox( NULL,
                     "Unable to open the File",
                     "Error!",
                     MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | 
                     MB_OK);
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
   char file_buffer[100000];
   fseek(fpSend, 0, SEEK_END);
   size_t file_size = ftell(fpSend);
   fseek(fpSend, 0, SEEK_SET);
   if(file_size>0)   //if file size>0
      {
         int bytes_read=0;
         if((bytes_read=fread(file_buffer, file_size, 1, fpSend))<=0)
            {
            //"Unable to copy file into buffer",
            }
            //"File copied in Buffer",

         if(sendto(socketIdentifier, file_buffer, file_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &AH_glb_connectedSocket, sizeof(AH_glb_connectedSocket))<0)
            {
                //"Not Sent"
            }
         else
            {
                //"File Sent Successfully!",
                sendCount = sendCount+1;
                memset(file_buffer, 0, sizeof(file_buffer));
            }

               }
          break;
              default:
                 return 0;
               }
     break;
    }  
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd )
{
   //window created.

   while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
      {         
         TranslateMessage(&Msg);
         DispatchMessage(&Msg);
      }
   return Msg.wParam;


   closesocket(socketIdentifier);
   WSACleanup();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A problem is no `fclose()`. Eventually, the process will run out of file descriptors.

Comment: @hmjd : +1, for pointing out the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any fclose() here. Maybe you run out of resources?

This sounds rather similar:

[Why would fopen fail to open a file that exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690018/why-would-fopen-fail-to-open-a-file-that-exists?rq=1)

When no fclose is done, it will eventually fail to find a new file descriptor, as they are limited.

Comment: Thank you so much. This exactly was the problem :)